# Android - Running next if on second button click

Tags: java, android

as subject says I'm looking for a way to run first if on first click on the button and run next if on click on the button
Here is what i tried

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.welcomeButton);
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeText);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View p1)
    {

        int x = 1;

        if (x == 1)
        {
            textView.setText(R.string.step1);
            button.setText("Next");

            // heres increment of the variable x so on next click x will be 2 and the next if will be run instead
            x++;
        }
        if (x == 2)
        {
            textView.setText(R.string.step2);
            button.setText("Next");
        }


    }
});
```

as you can see there's a increment on first `if` so it increases the variable x and next time that button is clicked x is 2 and second one will run ,
but the problem is on first button click it runs the first `if` then increase the variable and runs next `if` i want it to run first if only on first click  . how can i do this in this method ?
is it better to use a `case` if yes please give me an example of it 
thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that you have a variable that only lives for as long as your `onClick` does. This means that every time you click the button, a new `x` with value 1 is initialized, so your increment won't work

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE oh . so thats a problem . how can i do it in another way then  ? thanks .

Comment: `if` statement is always `true`. The IDE must be screaming that at you!

Comment: `int x = 1;` above `@Override` line (not inside method, but inside `OnClickListener`) and `if (x == 2)` to `else if (x == 2)`

Comment: @snachmsm Does that work in an anonymous class?

Comment: @snachmsm thanks that done it perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `x` a member variable of your class. So somewhere in your class you have to define it like

```
private int x = 1;
```

and change your `onClick` method to this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View p1)
{
    if (x == 1)
    {
        textView.setText(R.string.step1);
        button.setText("Next");

        // heres increment of the variable x so on next click x will be 2 and the next if will be run instead
        x++;
    }
    if (x == 2)
    {
        textView.setText(R.string.step2);
        button.setText("Next");
    }
}
```

You probably need to reset `x` somewhere too

Comment: thanks . it did the job , i also replaced the second if with else if to first one

Answer (score 0):

You're putting `x` `equal` **1** each time user clicks on button.

put `x` **outside** of `onClick` method and problem will be solve!

Comment: yes i found out my mistake by above answer and also i needed to use else if instead of the second if . and dude its not nice to give a -1 im not a expert everyone make mistakes while learning and coding :(

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: You need to make x a member variable of your class else it will always be initialized to 1 :

```
private int x = 1;
```

Step 2: Let's take a look at the code. So the declaration and initialization of x can be removed.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.welcomeButton);
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeText);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View p1)
    {
        //int x = 1; //Now a member variable of the class.
        if (x == 1)
        {
            textView.setText(R.string.step1);
            button.setText("Next");

            // heres increment of the variable x so on next click x will be 2 and the next if will be run instead
            x++;
        }
        else if (x == 2) //if (x == 2) Done so that once it checks the first if it will just move on
        {
            textView.setText(R.string.step2);
            button.setText("Next");
        }
    }
});
```

I've made a comment next to where you problem is.
It's that you are using an if instead of an else if.
When code is running all if conditions are checked regardless of whether one of the if blocks have been executed. So in the case in point you increment and then the program checks the next if and then Voila! another if block that can be executed.

Comment: Yes that's the solution. Two post above did answered the same and on its comments I said that I needed the else if for it and needed to put the variable outside . Thanks for answering :)